# Airflow cannot open .cache file

Tags: airflow, spotify, spotipy

I am trying to automate the flow of calling Spotify. I am nearly there but I am held up at one point.

I am using Airflow (ETL tool) to run my python scripts.

I am able to connect using the spotipy module but it cannot read/access the .cache-'username' file which it needs to. I am running on a Debian Google Cloud Compute instance.

The error is

Couldn't write token to cache at: .cache-'username'

Comment: did you make it?

Answer (score 0):

Spotify automatically creates a `.cache` file when you are using the API. If this file exists, Spotify will try to use it, and will throw an error if the file is not usable (the file may be cache from another process, or it is trying to access `.cache` for something that isnt there).

To solve this, simply remove the `.cache` file, (`rm .cache`) and Spotify will function properly without trying to use cache.